# apply changes after reboot, Source code

Tags: java, android, reboot, xposed

I'm making a Xposed applications and want to know if there is a way to apply the interface changes after restarting the Phone, for example if I want to change the color of the notification bar, i select the color, and the change applied after reboot, whats code i need? whats function is?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an app that takes the user's preference for the colors and stores in a shared preference file, and then hook into the system android package onLoad (which only happens once per boot), and have it apply the changes.